# Mirage Passthrough returns Response Object instead of JSON data returned from network call

Tags: fetch, pass-through, ember-cli-mirage

I am getting an error:

```
Mirage: Your Ember app tried to GET 'http://localhost:3006/data.json', 
but there was no route defined to handle this request. 
Define a route that matches this path in your mirage/config.js file. 
Did you forget to add your namespace?
```

So following the documentation of mirage i added this:

```
this.passthrough('http://localhost:3006/data.json');
```

Even though after adding passthrough, I am getting such Response instead of JSON Object returned from the network api call.

The Actual Request i am making is:

```
fetch(`${host}/data.json`)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => {
   // my operation on data
});
```

The response i am getting is:

```
{bodyUsed: true
headers: Headers {map: {…}}
ok: true
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
type: "default"
url: "http://localhost:3006/data.json"
_bodyInit: null
_bodyText: ""}
```

But I am expecting:

```
 { 
   "files": 
         { 
              "x": "any", 
              "a": "any", 
              "b": "any", 
              "c": "any" 
         } 
 }
```

I kept a debugger in Pretender.js which is sending the FakeRequest and there in its object, I see that FakeRequest has responseType="" and response as null. And somehow my responseText has value but that is not considered and response value is considered and receiving null.

Also there is a logic which is return saying

```
"response" in xhr ? xhr.response : xhr.responseText
```

In this case i have response property but its value is null. Hence according to the above condition it is returning xhr.response which is null

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Hm that's strange. I can't see anything obvious that would cause it. Could you share the code that's making the request? Also, if you could share a reproduction I'd be happy to take a look!

Comment: Hi @SamSelikoff, I have updated my post with request fetching information.

Comment: Thanks. I still can't see anything just from your question. Any chance you could upload + share a simplified reproduction?